# htaccess rule not redirecting to https as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, this seems like it should be fairly straight forward, if the request is not https or the request uses the www prefix redirect to https with out www. Using the following rewrite rule seems like it should accomplish both of the following, but for some reason does not. Any suggestions?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What do you get when you try it http or using www?

Comment: `code`http://domain.org and http://www.domain.org
both redirect to https://domain.org as expected.

Comment: However, https://www.domain.org does not redirect.

Comment: Try my answer and only change the domain.

Comment: Also try it in a different browser or refresh cache after making change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure rewrite engine is on and that you have have AllowOverride set to `All` in apache config. Try it this way and see if it works. I use this exact code for my site and it works perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works for all but https with www still getting the same result.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? This definitely works.

Comment: I did. Still no luck.

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess file? I don't see why it's not working for you.

Comment: updated original question with full text of htaccess.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The problem I was seeing was not that the site was not redirecting, rather that the browser security warning was being triggered before the redirect.  
  
This is a well documented problem. Just a rookie mistake on my part.  Final solution in this case was to purchase a seperate ssl for the www domain as well.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. On a another note, MOST CA's give you both the domain and www versions so that is typically not an issue. One way to get both is to only order the www version and they will give you non www version included. If they don't, buy it somewhere else.